# Is it possible to kill the stored procedure when Azure Data Factory Activity timesout?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

we have a number of pipelines where its activities can timeout. We thought that when an activity timeout happened the stored procedures running under those activities would stop too. But it turns out that despite pipeline activities can timeout the stored procedures still runs. this can lead to a strange behavior if we rerun the activities. so we would like to know how to deal with this situation so when the activity fails the stored procedure running under it also fails.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two possible fixes here:

**1. Stored Procedure Activity**

The stored procedure activity in your pipeline has a property for timeout, default to 7 days.

[image: stored procedure activity]

**2. Connection String**

Under Linked Services, click "{}" to see the code behind your connection to the Azure SQL Database, and then adjust the "connection timeout" properly (default is 30 seconds).

[image: connection string]

[image: connection timeout]

Comment: Hi Diego Thanks, the first one I'm sure It does not work because that's what I have. even if it timesout the procedure keeps running. I suspect the second one will happen to likewise but I have to test and later I'll come back to you

Comment: OK, here to help if needed ;)